# Как создать свой класс String в Java?

Tags: java, android, строки

Привет, на собеседовании на Android Dev задали вопрос как создать свой Java String class. Я не смог ответить. На С++ я примерно понимаю что там можно с указателями на массив работать (char[]) и т.д. Кто может помогите, может небольшая имплементация с примером использовани или пару ссылок на примеры. Буду рад любой помощи! Спасибо!

Comment: Собственно сам class [String](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java)

Comment: Бывает так, что на собеседованиях задают вопросы, не предполагающие прямого ответа. Возможно, правильным ответом было бы - "Позиция Android Dev не предполагает разработку своего собственного JDK". Вы же не в Oracle устраиваетесь, в конце концов...

Comment: Может имеется ввиду как унаследоваться от String, тогда ни как, от него не возможно унаследоваться так как он final, а если именно создать просто класс, то все просто, сохраняем массив charoв внутри класса.